# State Space Model

Tags: control-systems

I want to calculate State Space Model, there are four matrix:

```
A={{-0.01814,0.008163,0.002041},{0.0002838,-0.0004258,0},{0.02041,0,-0.02332}}
B={{0,1.389e-005},{0.0001419,0},{0.002915,0}}
C={{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}}
D={{0,0}{0,0},{0,0}}
```

In Matlab I use `ss` function and it works perfectly but in matematica something goes wrong. I tried to do it by using `StateSpaceModel` but there is an error:

```
StateSpaceModel[{{-0.01814,0.008163,0.002041},{0.0002838,-0.0004258,0}\
,{0.02041,0,-0.02332}},{{0,-5+1.389 \
e},{0.0001419,0},{0.002915,0}},{{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}},{{0,0},{0,0}}\
] is not a valid
```

my code is:

```
a = {{-0.01814, 0.008163, 0.002041}, {0.0002838, -0.0004258, 
   0}, {0.02041, 0, -0.02332}}
b = {{0, 1.389 e - 005}, {0.0001419, 0}, {0.002915, 0}}
c = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
d = {{0, 0} {0, 0}, {0, 0}}
ss = StateSpaceModel[a, b , c , d]
StateResponse[ss, UnitStep[1]]
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

@Update

There is one more problem, `StateSpaceModel` builds correct but how is it possible to get plot for step(like for `step(ss)` - Matlab outputs plots). I use:

```
ss = StateSpaceModel[{a, b, c, d}]
StateResponse[ss, UnitStep[t], t]
```

and the result is just text:

```
a = {{-0.01814, 0.008163, 0.002041}, {0.0002838, -0.0004258, 
   0}, {0.02041, 0, -0.02332}}
b = {{0, 1.389*10^(-5)}, {0.0001419, 0}, {0.002915, 0}}
c = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
d = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}
ss = StateSpaceModel[{a, b, c, d}]
StateResponse[ss, UnitStep[t], t]

    Plot[%, {t, 0, 10}]



    {{-0.01814, 0.008163, 0.002041}, {0.0002838, -0.0004258, 0}, {0.02041,
       0, -0.02332}}

    {{0, 0.00001389}, {0.0001419, 0}, {0.002915, 0}}

    {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}

    {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}

    StateSpaceModel[{{{-0.01814, 0.008163, 
        0.002041}, {0.0002838, -0.0004258, 0}, {0.02041, 
        0, -0.02332}}, {{0, 0.00001389}, {0.0001419, 0}, {0.002915, 
        0}}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 
        0}}}, SamplingPeriod ->None, SystemsModelLabels -> None]

    {{E^(-0.0418858 t) (-6.34388*10^-18 E^(0.0141746 t) - 
         8.22162*10^-18 E^(0.0279927 t) - 
         1.31901*10^-17 E^(0.0416043 t) + 
         0.0159398 E^(0.0141746 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         1.38778*10^-17 E^(0.014456 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         0.0264835 E^(0.0279927 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         1.38778*10^-17 E^(0.0282742 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         0.262112 E^(0.0416043 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         0.272656 E^(0.0418858 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         2.71051*10^-20 E^(0.0554974 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         1.73472*10^-18 E^(0.0557039 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         6.77626*10^-21 E^(0.0693156 t) UnitStep[t]), 
      E^(-0.0418858 t) (6.59836*10^-20 E^(0.0141746 t) + 
         1.73256*10^-19 E^(0.0279927 t) - 
         2.59348*10^-17 E^(0.0416043 t) - 
         0.000165792 E^(0.0141746 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         2.1684*10^-19 E^(0.014456 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         0.000558093 E^(0.0279927 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         1.35525*10^-20 E^(0.0280677 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         1.6263*10^-18 E^(0.0282742 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         0.515375 E^(0.0416043 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         0.514983 E^(0.0418858 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         1.0842*10^-19 E^(0.0554974 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         2.71051*10^-20 E^(0.0557039 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         5.42101*10^-20 E^(0.0693156 t) UnitStep[t]), 
      E^(-0.0418858 t) (2.94856*10^-17 E^(0.0141746 t) - 
         1.78005*10^-17 E^(0.0279927 t) - 
         1.16852*10^-17 E^(0.0416043 t) - 
         0.0740865 E^(0.0141746 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         2.77556*10^-17 E^(0.014456 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         0.0573388 E^(0.0279927 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         1.38778*10^-17 E^(0.0280677 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         6.93889*10^-17 E^(0.0282742 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         0.232207 E^(0.0416043 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         0.363632 E^(0.0418858 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         1.35525*10^-20 E^(0.0554974 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         3.38813*10^-20 E^(0.0693156 t)
           UnitStep[t])}, {E^(-0.0418858 t) (3.39529*10^-20 E^(
          0.0141746 t) + 7.17951*10^-20 E^(0.0279927 t) + 
         2.67223*10^-21 E^(0.0416043 t) - 
         0.00015845 E^(0.0141746 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         0.000674828 E^(0.0279927 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         2.71051*10^-20 E^(0.0280677 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         5.42101*10^-20 E^(0.0282742 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         0.00043952 E^(0.0416043 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         0.0012728 E^(0.0418858 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         4.23516*10^-22 E^(0.0693156 t) UnitStep[t]), 
      E^(-0.0418858 t) (-3.53149*10^-22 E^(0.0141746 t) - 
         1.51296*10^-21 E^(0.0279927 t) + 
         5.25424*10^-21 E^(0.0416043 t) + 
         1.64806*10^-6 E^(0.0141746 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         2.11758*10^-22 E^(0.014456 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         0.0000142208 E^(0.0279927 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         4.23516*10^-22 E^(0.0280677 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         0.000864202 E^(0.0416043 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         0.000848333 E^(0.0418858 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         1.69407*10^-21 E^(0.0554974 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         4.23516*10^-22 E^(0.0693156 t) UnitStep[t]), 
      E^(-0.0418858 t) (-1.57809*10^-19 E^(0.0141746 t) + 
         1.55442*10^-19 E^(0.0279927 t) + 
         2.36735*10^-21 E^(0.0416043 t) + 
         0.000736458 E^(0.0141746 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         0.00146106 E^(0.0279927 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         4.33681*10^-19 E^(0.0280677 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         1.0842*10^-19 E^(0.0282742 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         0.000389374 E^(0.0416043 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         0.00111397 E^(0.0418858 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         8.47033*10^-22 E^(0.0554974 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         5.42101*10^-20 E^(0.0557039 t) UnitStep[t])}}
```

How can I get plots?

Comment: `1.389e-005` does not have your intended meaning in _Mathematica_. Try `1.389*^(-5)`

Comment: Use `ss = StateSpaceModel[{a, b, c, d}]` not `ss = StateSpaceModel[a, b, c, d]`.

Answer (score 3):

*(I voted the question to be closed since following the function pages of `StateSpaceModel` and `StateResponse` would show quite clearly what is wrong...)*

Wrong syntax is used in question's code. Here is that code with fixes:

```
a = {{-0.01814, 0.008163, 0.002041}, {0.0002838, -0.0004258, 
   0}, {0.02041, 0, -0.02332}}
b = {{0, 1.389*^-5}, {0.0001419, 0}, {0.002915, 0}}
c = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
d = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}

ss = StateSpaceModel[{a, b, c, d}]
```

[image]

```
StateResponse[ss, UnitStep[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[#, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All] & /@ Flatten[%]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for youe help. I edited my post but probably it is invisible. Now my code works but how is it possible to plot response for step? (In matlab its just `step(ss)`)

Answer (score 0):

To get the step response, use the `OutputResponse[ ]` function. Building off of @Anton Antonov's answer, we will apply a `UnitStep[ ]` to the first of the two inputs to get the response by the three outputs:

```
    {r1, r2, r3} = OutputResponse[ss, {1, 0} UnitStep[t], t] // Chop //Flatten;
    Plot[{r1, r2, r3}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Step response to second input

```
    {r1, r2, r3} = OutputResponse[ss, {0, 1} UnitStep[t], t]// Chop//Flatten;
    Plot[{r1, r2, r3}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]